# Virtualbox causes problems with inux OS, so I need a distro that is dependable on virtual machines

Tags: distributions

Host: Windows 10 64bit, Virtualbox v6.1

Mint didn't like being virtual. eg: Updater didn't work could not update Firefox. Video and audio glitches.

Lubuntu didn't like being virtual. eg: Have to use the terminal every time I start the OS to get the right aspect ratio. Other flaws: Software installation omits making shortcuts or desktop icons. No middle mouse wheel feature for free scrolling.

I want to choose from a list, use icons, select radio buttons, move a slider, and everything works. If I can never look at another terminal again it will be too soon.

All I want is a virtual machine to run online features that compliments my offline machine.

Any distro come to mind for my needs?

Comment: We'll need a little more info. What is the operating environment? Virtualisation on a desktop, server, etc? Also, what is your host operating system?

Comment: Linux (and the many distros) is _designed_ around the idea of running inside a virtual machine. Whether it is running under a hypervisor or inside a virtual machine application. This suggests that the problem is not in the distro, but how you are installing and using it--and that will not change by simply moving to another distro. Likewise, for a VM _application_ (instead of a hypervisor), you will always have some issues regarding wrapping the guest OS inside a window on the host OS, and handling special system signals, keypresses, etc.

Comment: @C.M. It's not the distro it's you. Wow! Do you work in the warranty department?

Comment: I do not see the relevance of your comment. First, if the first sentence is a paraphrase of what I said, it is not even close to what I said. Second, if you do not like a comment or answer, just ignore it. I am trying to be helpful here, and pointing out that what you are asking is likely not going to get a satisfactory answer because of the reasons I gave.

Comment: If you can't get (2) of the most stable distros to work, then something else is wrong. I would check the following: make sure VB is at the latest version (currently v6.1.26), verify that **VB Extension Pack** has been installed, verify that **Guest Additions** is installed on the VM.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I have v6.1.22 with VB extension packs added plus Guest addition installed with great difficulty. Linux Mint was a few years ago when I said that's it I'm done with Linux forever. As soon as I try again I realize I am a glutton for punishment.

Comment: I wasn't happy with my W10 host/LM guest setup either. What I would suggest is trying VMware Player - it's also free and I've been extremely happy with it (although my host is LM).

Answer (score 0):

Try Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu.

Lubuntu is very sparse, in the sense that many operations required using the terminal, which can be quite frustrating for someone who just want to use the OS without needing to search for special instructions to feed into the terminal.

Installing Ubuntu is a way more enjoyable experience, basically offered all the graphical interface needed to facilitate installation.

eg: Installing the Guest Addition, when you instruct the virtual machine to insert a virtual CD, a disk icon appears on the desktop then from there you can chose to run the disk. This alone will save you time and research compared to Lubuntu where you need to instruct the OS with command lines to install the guest editions, command lines that you have to search the internet to find the right instructions for it to install.

No terminal operation is needed to install the OS in Virtualbox. Unless you need to do specific tweaking.